# (Symfony2) how to show data based on a dropdown list item from the data base

Tags: ajax, symfony

i want to get from the data base users after filtring them by city ( i got city and user as entities) here is my code i tried it at the first time it worked , but the i got this error :

> Variable "users" does not exist in otaotaBundle:Evenement:invitEvt.html.twig at line 20

here is my controller

```
public function invitEvtAction($id)
{ 
    //the city's form
    $form = $this->get('form.factory')->create(new PaysType());


    $request=$this->getRequest();
    if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST')
    {
           $city= $form->get('pays')->getData();

            //get user by city 
            $users = $this->getDoctrine()
                        ->getManager()
                        ->getRepository('otaUserBundle:User')
                        ->selectVoisin($city);

            //send mail ....

        }
        return $this->render('otaotaBundle:Evenement:invitEvt.html.twig', array(
            'form' => $form->createView(),
            'users'=>$users,
            ));
```

}

and the view html.twig

```html
<form method="post" novalidate>
    
     <div>
        
        {{ form_widget(form.pays) }}
    </div>
    
    <div class="CSSTableManipule" >
        <table>
            
            {% for us in users %}
                {# ... #}
            {% endfor %}
        </table>
    </div>
        <br/><br/>
      <button  type="submit">Envoyer</button>    
</form>
```

and the city's form :

```
{   
/**
 * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
 * @param array $options
 */
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('pays', 'entity', array(
              'class' => 'otaUserBundle:Pays',
              'property' => 'pays', ));
}
```

any help :/ .??

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead (assuming `voisin` is a property of the User entity and may equal the value of `$city` for one or more records):

```
        $users = $this->getDoctrine()
                    ->getManager()
                    ->getRepository('otaUserBundle:User')
                    ->findAll(['voisin' => $city]);
```